# $RECYCLE.BIN Directory appeared recently on my hard drives

Tags: recycle-bin

I just started seeing a $RECYCLE.BIN directory on all my internal and external hard drives. I had made no changes to folder options on Windows Explorer, in fact not configuration changes recently. It may be related to plugging in a USB stick with viruses - my virus software found them and immediately deleted them. I am not sure if this is the cause though. I am concerned as to why these directories have appeared. Anyone got any advice? I am using Windows 7. Thanks

Comment: did you tell Explorer to show hidden files?

Answer (score 2):

Did you disable the "Hide protected operating system files"?
From File Explorer, Go to View tab > Click > Options > View Tab.
Check the option and Apply.

Answer (score 1):

It's part of the spam folders of Windows and will always be there. It contains the content of the Recycle Bin. As this one, there are many others. If you delete it, it will re-appear (and will remove the contents of Recycle Bin).

Comment: Why do you call it a "spam folder"? The recycle bin is a useful construct--`rm` is difficult to undo.